# Asymptotic equivalence between cross validation and bayesian information criteria

Tags: cross-validation, references, bic

I heard that Bayesian information criteria and cross validation are asymptotically equivalent when the size of validation set is large enough similar to the relationship between Akaike information criteria and leave one out cross validation.

But, I cannot find the paper or references about the connection between Bayesian information criteria and cross validation.

So, I would be so thankful if you could give me references.

Comment: To my knowledge there is not such a relation. Bic is estimating twice the negative log marginal likelihood which is different than the cross validation goal of aic and takeuchi information criterion.